# How do i change table content on mouse over?

Tags: javascript, html, css

What can i do this in and how?

Comment: You mean the innerHTML of a table??? PS: Shortest question ever...

Comment: you need to provide more detail and show code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a simple little example for you:

```
<html>
<head>
<script>
function changeTDContents(text)
{
    document.getElementById("cell").innerHTML = text
}
</script>
</head>
<body>
<table onmouseover="javascript:changeTDContents('world!');" onmouseout="javascript:changeTDContents('Hello');">
<tr><td id="cell">Hello</td></tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

Should be fairly self-explanatory.

Answer (score 1):

JQuery mouseover event handlers will let you set the contents of any HTML element.

http://api.jquery.com/mouseover/ - the example here uses DIV elements but you should be able to shift it to use a table

Comment: ah, DIVs...no one uses tables anymore...